# Contar número de filas de otra tabla en codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Pues eso, necesito hacer un conteo de las filas de otra tabla para mostrarlo en pantalla, el problema es el siguiente: tengo una tabla de elementos en la que cada uno de esos elementos contiene un número limitado de items, la idea es contar esos items y mostrarlo junto a los elementos. ¿Alguna solución?

**Tabla Elementos con nº Plazas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla items a contar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Controlador**

```
 public function intervalos_lista() {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        //$crud->unset_bootstrap();
        //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/header.php'  ------------- /
        $datos = array(
            'title' => "Franjas Horarias", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
            'username' => "Administrador"
        );

        $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);

        $crud->set_language("spanish");
        $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');
        $crud->set_table('intervaloshorarios');
        $crud->order_by('intervaloHorario', 'asc');

        $crud->display_as('idIntervaloHorario', 'Intervalo Horario');
        $crud->set_subject('Franja Horaria');
        $crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario', 'entregas', 'numeroEntrega');
        //Para cambiar los nombres de las columnas usar el display_as
        //http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/display_as
        $crud->display_as('intervaloHorario', 'Franja Horaria')->display_as('numeroVehiculos', 'Plazas Disponibles');
        $crud->callback_column('intervaloHorario', array($this, '_callback_intervalo_horario'));

        //Para que solo salgan los campos necesarios
        //$crud->columns('nombreCurso');
        //$crud->fields('nombreCurso');
        //$crud->unset_add();
        /* if ($this->uri->segment(3) != '') {
          $crud->where('idIntervaloHorario', $this->uri->segment(3));
          } */
        $output = $crud->render();

        //Para quitar el id simplemente quito aquí el campo del id de la base de datos
        //$crud->fields('lastName','firstName','extension','email','jobTitle');

        $this->_example_output($output);


        //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/footer.php'  ------------- /
        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
    }
```

**Base de datos**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Hola no entendí bien tu pregunta pero creo que lo puedes solucionar asi.

Si deseas saber cuantas filas tiene una tabla solo has un SELECT * FROM tabla y luego usas num_rows().

```
$query=$this->db->get("mi_tabla");
$numero_filas=$query->num_rows();
```

puedes revisar la documentación oficial para orientarte un poco más.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html